# Why is the "q-Pochhammer Symbol" referred to as such, despite not being a q-analog of the Pochhammer symbol?

Tags: combinatorics, q-analogs, pochhammer-symbol

The q-Pochhammer symbol (for $k>0$): $(a;q)_k = \prod\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-aq^j\right)$

The Pochhammer symbol / rising factorial: $(a)_k = \prod\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}(a+j)$

The falling factorial (sometimes identified with the Pochhammer symbol instead of the above): $a^\underline{n} = \prod\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}(a-j)$

The q-Pochhammer symbol is supposedly the [q-analog](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-Analog.html) of the Pochhammer symbol, meaning if we set $q=1$, we get the Pochhammer symbol. [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html) makes this claim, as does Wikipedia and [this very site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pochhammer-symbol). Yet it it clearly false. For example, $(3;1)_2 = 4$ whereas $(3)_2 = 12$ and $3^\underline{2} = 6$. So we have an inappropriate name ("q-Pochhammer symbol", which suggests it is a q-analog) and a clearly false statement (that it is indeed a q-analog), both apparently widespread and generally accepted. What's going on here?

Comment: Another name for the "q-Pochammer symbol" appears to be the "q-shifted factorial" (see for instance Gaspar and Rahmann's "Basic Hypergeometric Series".) But that name seems equally inscrutable.

Comment: I will also note that one does have $\lim_{q\to 1}\dfrac{(q^a,q)_n}{(1-q)^n}=(a)_n$. So the two concepts are related in the $q\to 1$ limit, but it seems quite strange to refer to the former as though it's a q-analog of the latter.

Comment: Where does Mathworld make that claim? I see the limit from @Semiclassical's second comment in the linked page.

Comment: I don't see Mathworld making the claim explicitly either. For instance, the page on q-analogs explicitly requires that the limit $q\to 1$ restore the original object and does not list the q-Pochammer symbol as an example of such in the text. That said they do link their page on q-Pochammer symbols from their q-analog page, so the implication that the former is an instance of the latter is certainly present.

Comment: For a related instance of "not really a q-analog" on Mathworld see their page on [q-Hypergeometric functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-HypergeometricFunction.html), especially equation (9). Wikipedia, by contrast, has the same content under the heading of "basic hypergeometric series", though they do reference the q-hypergeometric name as well.

Comment: @Semiclassical The very first words on the page are "The q-analog of the Pochhammer symbol". Doesn't get more explicit than that.